# funcall inside local-set-key

Tags: key-bindings, symbols, funcall

Programming Perl in cperl-mode I often use `_` symbol, so I decided to remap it with `/` symbol, so I could type faster. I created the following functions:

```
(defun add-underscore ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "_"))

(defun add-backslash ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "/"))

(defun my-cperl-mode ()
  "Perl mode customisations."
  (local-set-key (kbd "/") 'add-underscore)
  (local-set-key (kbd "_") 'add-backslash)
)

(add-hook 'cperl-mode-hook 'my-cperl-mode)
```

Then I decided to merge similar functions into one and created this:

```
(defun output-symbol (symbol)
  (interactive)
  (insert symbol))

(defun my-cperl-mode ()
  "Perl mode customisations."
  (local-set-key (kbd "/") (funcall output-symbol ?\_))
  (local-set-key (kbd "_") (funcall output-symbol ?\/))
)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. What is wrong?

Comment: FYI - This: `(local-set-key (kbd "/") 'add-underscore)` is the same as this: `(local-set-key (kbd "/") "_")`.

Comment: @Drew But you can't transpose keys that way: the macros would call each other indefinitely.

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, if you use two like that. I was speaking generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most Lisp dialects, including Emacs Lisp, [symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html) have a value as a variable which is independent of their function definition. `(funcall output-symbol …)` refers to the variable-value of `output-symbol`, not to the function. You could refer to the function instead by passing the symbol itself to `funcall`: if you pass a symbol to `funcall`, it uses that symbol's function definition. This means [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) the symbol: `(funcall 'output-symbol …)`. But this won't work because…

You run `(funcall …)` at the time you define the key binding. This is pointless. `(funcall 'output-symbol ?_)` is just a complicated way of writing `(output-symbol ?_)`. (The reason `funcall` exists is when you want to call a function reference stored in a variable.) You want to delay the call to `output-symbol`, so you need to put it inside a function — you need to *add* a layer of function abstraction, not remove one: `(local-set-key (kbd "/") (lambda () (output-symbol ?_)))`. But this won't work because…

A key can only be bound to a [command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html), i.e. a function that has an `interactive` specification. A function that calls a function that has an `interactive` specification isn't good enough. You need `(local-set-key (kbd "/") (lambda () (interactive) (output-symbol ?_)))`. You don't really save anything with the `output-symbol` function, but it does work.

By the way, the `interactive` specification in the definition of `output-symbol` is useless: it specifies that `output-symbol` receives zero arguments when called interactively, so an interactive call would fail.

Before I go further, let me mention that calling `local-set-key` in a mode hook is weird: you're doing the keymap customization each time the mode starts. This is weird but ok for your own use; it wouldn't be acceptable in a package because you'd be overriding the user's customizations. The normal way to customize key bindings in a particular mode is to use [`define-key`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html#index-define_002dkey) on that mode's keymap. Do this after the `cperl` module is loaded, by registering a function with `eval-after-load`.

```
(defun my-cperl-mode-customizations ()
  (define-key cperl-mode-map (kbd "_") (lambda () (interactive) …))
  )
(eval-after-load "cperl-mode" '(my-cperl-mode-customizations))
```

You can avoid repeating the interactive specification by using a function that builds a command, instead of using an auxiliary function.

```
(defun make-insert-command (text)
  (lexical-let ((text text))
    #'(lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (insert text))))

(defun my-cperl-mode-customizations ()
  (define-key cperl-mode-map (kbd "_") (make-insert-command "/"))
  (define-key cperl-mode-map (kbd "/") (make-insert-command "_"))
  )
(eval-after-load "cperl-mode" '(my-cperl-mode-customizations))
```

The `make-insert-command` command isn't very nice. Here are a few ways to improve it:

- Add `*` to the interactive specification so that the command errors out if the buffer is read-only.
- Add `p` to the interactive specification to allow inserting the character multiple times with a prefix argument. The function needs a count argument to receive the prefix argument.
- Call [`undo-auto-amalgamate`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Undo.html#index-undo_002dauto_002damalgamate) so that typing `foo_bar` will be a single undo action, as it is when `_` is an ordinary key.

```
(defun make-insert-command (text)
  (lexical-let ((text text))
    #'(lambda (&optional n)
        (interactive "*p")
        (undo-auto-amalgamate)
        (or n (setq n 1))
        (let ((i 0))
          (while (< i n)
            (setq i (1+ i))
            (insert text))))))
(defun my-cperl-mode-customizations ()
  (define-key cperl-mode-map (kbd "_") (make-insert-command "/"))
  (define-key cperl-mode-map (kbd "/") (make-insert-command "_"))
  )
(eval-after-load "cperl-mode" '(my-cperl-mode-customizations))
```

This is still not very nice because the binding for `_` and `/` will appear as some unreadable Lisp code in help. Anonymous commands are possible, but for this reason (as well as other reasons that don't matter here — some aspects of interactive commands depend on the command symbol's property list, and that requires the command to be a symbol bound to an interactive function and not directly an interactive function).

Comment: Unfortunately the call to `lambda`, generated by `make-insert-command` gives an error: `funcall-interactively: Symbol’s value as variable is void: text`. Seems, that inside `lambda` we can't see the definition of `text` parameter.

Comment: I changed `make-insert-command` to the working version. This is related to the lexical binding of symbols, which is required for creating closures. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593383/how-do-i-do-closures-in-emacs-lisp

Answer (score 1):

1. You're missing a quote: `(funcall 'output-symbol ?\_)`

   If you want to call the `symbol-function` of the symbol `output-symbol` then you need to pass that symbol.  To do that, quote it, so evaluating returns the symbol.
2. But you don't need to do that.  To call a function whose name you already have, just call it directly: `(output-symbol ?\_)`.
3. But that's no good, because you need to bind a key to a *command*, that is, (1) a function that (2) has an `interactive` spec.

```lisp
(defun output-symbol (symbol)
  (insert symbol))

(defun my-cperl-mode ()
  "Perl mode customisations."
  (local-set-key (kbd "/") (lambda () (interactive) (output-symbol ?\_)))
  (local-set-key (kbd "_") (lambda () (interactive) (output-symbol ?\/))))
```

Or just what you had in the beginning.  Or just

```lisp
(defun my-cperl-mode ()
  "Perl mode customisations."
  (local-set-key (kbd "/") (lambda () (interactive) (insert ?_)))
  (local-set-key (kbd "_") (lambda () (interactive) (insert ?/))))
```